# ExecuteExcel4Macro - 1004 error on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm new to creating Macros. I am recording a simple macro that creates a data graph using two columns. When I run the macro code I keep getting the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> The formula you typed contains an error.• To get assistance in
>   entering a function, click OK,then click Function on the Insert menu.
>   • If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign
>   (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (').

Here is the VB code:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+p
'
    Range("A1:B39").Select
    ExecuteExcel4Macro (FALSE,240,73)
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'5E627659 host-260'!$A$1:$B$39")
End Sub
```

I'm running Excel 2016 for Mac. When I try the same thing on a Windows machine, it works.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Not sure what the second line is doing? That's supposed to be executing a macro name enclosed in a string

Comment: Perhaps `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(FALSE,240,73)`?

Comment: I tried Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro and still get the same error.